# Cumulative distribution over a set

Tags: probability

If $F$ is an arbitrary cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$, and $S$ a subset of the support of $X$, what does $F(S)$ mean? Is it $\int_S dF(x)$ ?

In particular, if X is defined on $[0, 1]$, what does it mean to say that there is a set $S$ such that $F(S) = 1$?

This is probably a trivial question, but I have never seen this anywhere, except for old statistical learning papers (e.g. [1]), where it is used without a definition.

[[1]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2958556?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) Gordon, L., Olshen, R. A. (1978). Asymptotically efficient solutions to the
classification problem. Ann. Statist. 6 5 15-533.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and the associated [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) induced by that function.  For a real scalar random variable, the CDF is a function $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so it would not take a set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as an input at all.$^\dagger$

The probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and the corresponding CDF $F$ are related by the fact that:

$$\mathbb{P}(( -\infty, x ]) = F(x)
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

For a measureable set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{S}) = \int \limits_\mathcal{S} dF(x).$$

If $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{S}) = 1$ then it means that the random variable $X$ is somewhere in the set $\mathcal{S}$ with probability one (i.e., [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)).

---

$^\dagger$ As noted in the answer by [spiritlevel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/764422/spiritlevel), the notation $F(\mathcal{S})$ could arguably be used to refer to the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of $F$ on the set $\mathcal{S}$.  However, even if that were the intention, you would not get $F(\mathcal{S})=1$.  There is rarely any good reason to take the image of a CDF on a set.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I agree with you, but is it then standard abuse of notation to take $F(S)$ as $\mathbb P(S)$?

Comment: It's not an abuse of notation that I've seen, so I would say it is definitely non-standard (and a bit confusing).

Answer (score 1):

For a set $A$ in the domain of a function $f$, I've seen the following notation used quite a bit:
$$
f(A) = \{ f(a) : a\in A \}
$$